# elastic search type text does not give the result for match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have performed two queries

For first mapping is as shown here :

```
"customer_details": {
        "mappings": {
            "pan_details": {
                "properties": {
                    "city": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "college": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "customer_mame": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "doc_url": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "pan_no": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

for this when I write

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "match":{  
         "pan_no":"ABCDFGGG"
      }
   }
}
```

it gives me the result.

But when I am giving the mapping as shown below:

```
{
    "customer_details": {
        "mappings": {
            "pan_details": {
                "properties": {
                    "city": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "college": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "customer_name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "doc_url": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "pan_no": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the query as :

```
 {  
       "query":{  
          "match":{  
             "pan_no":"ABCDFGGG"
          }
       }
    }
```

it does not give me result at all.

The sample document is as given below :

```
{
    "customer_mame": "Marcus Rodriguez",
    "pan_no": "ABCDEGFTY",
    "city": "San Fransisco",
    "college": "UCSB",
    "doc_url": [
      "www.google.com",
      "www.facebook.com",
      "www.twitter.com"
    ]
  }
```

Now when I enter `pan_no` as `ABCD` something it should return me the above document.

Comment: can you show a document that is supposed to match?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are getting different results for the above mappings. Basically, both the mappings should produce the same results as they are same for the field **pan_no**. I  have tested your above mappings in my local environment and I am getting the same results. The default analyzer to text type is Standard Analyzer and would give the result for the query(according to your sample data):

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "match":{  
         "pan_no":"ABCDEGFTY"
      }
   }
}
```

> Now when I enter pan_no as ABCD something it should return me the
>   above document.

pan_no as ABCD won't result in any data for your sample as default analyzer is Standard analyzer.